# Why are code changes from vscode not reflected in my React server, even when terminal updates?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, webpack, sharetribe

I'm working on a React web server through Sharetribe, but the changes I code don't affect my server. However, I see them in terminal, and I get a message saying something like "restarting due to changes" or "webpack compiled successfully". For example, I created a new page component and added the necessary routing as well, but the path I created leads to a 404 error page.

I first tried to create a new page component, and when that didn't work I tried editing the path for an existing page component, but that didn't change anything in the server either and continued to direct me to the old page it originally routed to. I also saved all my files, ran a production build, repeatedly restarted the server, cleared browser cache, and enabled HMR.